# opengl render texture and switch between with mipmap or not

Tags: c, opengl, textures

I use this code to switch between images with mipmaps or not:

```
if ( tex->hasMipMaps ) {
            glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
            glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
        }
        else {
            glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
            glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        }
```

however this happens:
[image]

the table is rendered without mipmap,but when I change the register texture code to :

```
   // if ( tex->hasMipMaps ) {
                glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
                glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
            //}
            //else {
            //  glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
            //  glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
            //}
```

here is the result:
[image]
the mipmap works,but my font texture is kind missing,is there a way to render both textures that with mipmaps such as models  and  some textures without mipmaps such as font,particles?
do I need to call glTexParameteri to switch some states?

Comment: Valid values for GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER are GL_LINEAR and GL_NEAREST only. There is no mipmapping used for magnification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texture objects without a complete set of mipmaps will (generally) render white as you have seen.

You'll have to enable/disable mipmapping on a per-mesh level (assuming one texture per mesh) if some of your textures don't have mipmaps.